# Stream from WebClient into Flux. Blocking timeout throws exception

Tags: spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-reactive

I am calling a streaming API with a WebClient in a Spring Boot application.

I'd like to retrieve elements until I either received 10 elements, or 10 seconds have elapsed. I'd like the request to be blocking until either happens first.

```
        WebClient client = WebClient.builder().baseUrl(URL).build();

        List<Item> items = client
                .get()
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(Item.class)
                .limitRequest(10)
                .collectList()
                .block(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
```

If 10 items are retrieved before the timeout, the call nicely returns and I have a populated list of 10 items.

However, if the timeout passes first the following exception is thrown, and no items are returned.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timeout on blocking read for 10000 MILLISECONDS
```

**How can I read a stream up to x seconds and then return the retrieved items using the WebClient?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'd like to retrieve elements until I either received 10 elements, or 10 seconds have elapsed.

Sounds like [`bufferTimeout()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#bufferTimeout-int-java.time.Duration-) is exactly what you're after.

> Collect incoming values into multiple List buffers that will be emitted by the returned Flux each time the buffer reaches a maximum size OR the maxTime Duration elapses.

You just want one of these buffers. In a reactive context you'd then just call `next()` on the resulting flux - since you just want to block, you can just call `blockFirst()`.

Something like:

```
List<Item> items = client
        .get()
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToFlux(Item.class)
        .bufferTimeout(10, Duration.ofSeconds(10)) //first parameter is max number of elements, second is timeout
        .blockFirst();
```

Comment: Great. The `bufferTimeout()` is indeed what I was looking for, combined with `blockFirst()`.